# Singular solution of DE problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, singular-solution

Find the singular solution of the given de

$$y=x{dy\over dx}+a{dy\over dx}\left[1+\left({dy\over dx}\right)^2\right]^{-1\over 2}$$

My attempt : this is a clairaut's form of DE of the form $y=xp+ap(1+p^2)^{-1\over 2}$
so its solution is $y=xc+ac(1+c^2)^{-1\over 2}$.

Now we need to eliminate $p$ between $y(x)$ and $y'(x)$
going in this way and solving, differentiating i reach a point where i get

$$-x={a\over ({1+p^2})^{3 \over 2}} $$ then just reduce for $p$ and putting in the initial equation for y, thus getting a very complex equation. does it look good?

Answer (score 3):

Why not? In fact you have $$x=\frac{-a}{\sqrt{(1+c^2)^3}}\longrightarrow\sqrt{1+c^2}=\sqrt[3]{\frac{-a}{x}},~~~c=\pm\sqrt{\left(\frac{a}{x}\right)^{2/3}-1}$$ and so you will have, while we take the $+$ of above; $$y_{\text{singilar}}(x)=x\sqrt{(-a/x)^{2/3}-1}+\frac{a\sqrt{(-a/x)^{2/3}-1}}{(-a/x)^{1/3}}$$ For example and plotting the envelope here, I set $a=14$ and then;

[image]

Comment: Nice use of graphics! +1

Comment: @Amzoti: Thanks. I hope it helps the OP at least for $\epsilon>0$ however small.

Comment: $\overset{\star\star}{\smile}\quad$ Your efforts at MSE help this much: $\quad \lim_{\epsilon \to +\infty} \epsilon^\epsilon\quad \star$

Answer (score 0):

You get your singular solution from $$-x={a\over ({1+p^2})^{3 \over 2}}$$

**Process for finding Singular solution Solution:** $$-x={a\over ({1+p^2})^{3 \over 2}}$$
$$\implies ({1+p^2})^{3 \over 2}=-\frac{a}{x}$$
$$\implies 1+p^2=(\frac{a}{x})^{2 \over 3}$$
$$\implies p^2=\frac{a^{2 \over 3}-x^{2 \over 3}}{x^{2 \over 3}}$$
$$\implies p=\frac{dy}{dx}=\sqrt{\frac{a^{2 \over 3}-x^{2 \over 3}}{x^{2 \over 3}}}$$
$$dy=\sqrt{\frac{a^{2 \over 3}-x^{2 \over 3}}{x^{2 \over 3}}} ~dx\qquad . . . . . . .(1)$$

Putting $~a^{2 \over 3}-x^{2 \over 3}=u\implies du=-\frac{2}{3}x^{-{1 \over 3}}~dx$

From $(1)$, $$dy=-\frac{3}{2}u^{\frac{1}{2}}du$$Integrating,  $$y=-u^{\frac{3}{2}}=-(a^{2 \over 3}-x^{2 \over 3})^{\frac{3}{2}}$$

$$\implies x^{2 \over 3}+y^{2 \over 3}=a^{2 \over 3}$$This is the required singular solution.